# How can I install ftp server in kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, ftp

how install ftp server in kubuntu? please step by step, I installed by the comand sudo apt-get install vsftpd , but I cant connecting  using filezilla

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-an-FTP-Server-in-Ubuntu-Linux) tutorial. It also uses vsftpd, it must work in Lubuntu and other *buntu versions.